# AIX 7.1/ AIX 7.2 filesystem not persistently mounted across reboots and appears corrupted

Tags: filesystems, lvm, aix

OS: AIX 7.1 / AIX 7.2

Arch: ppc-64

I have created a custom (non-root) volume group homevg

```
bash-5.1# lsvg homevg
VOLUME GROUP:       homevg                   VG IDENTIFIER:  00c97c4000004b000000018577fceedd
VG STATE:           active                   PP SIZE:        512 megabyte(s)
VG PERMISSION:      read/write               TOTAL PPs:      799 (409088 megabytes)
MAX LVs:            256                      FREE PPs:       1 (512 megabytes)
LVs:                2                        USED PPs:       798 (408576 megabytes)
OPEN LVs:           1                        QUORUM:         2 (Enabled)
TOTAL PVs:          1                        VG DESCRIPTORS: 2
STALE PVs:          0                        STALE PPs:      0
ACTIVE PVs:         1                        AUTO ON:        yes
MAX PPs per VG:     32512                                     
MAX PPs per PV:     1016                     MAX PVs:        32
LTG size (Dynamic): 256 kilobyte(s)          AUTO SYNC:      no
HOT SPARE:          no                       BB POLICY:      relocatable 
PV RESTRICTION:     none                     INFINITE RETRY: no
DISK BLOCK SIZE:    512                      CRITICAL VG:    no
FS SYNC OPTION:     no
```

I have created logical volume homelv with jfs filesystem ( + homelvlog log device)

```
bash-5.1# lslv homelv
LOGICAL VOLUME:     homelv                 VOLUME GROUP:   homevg
LV IDENTIFIER:      00c97c4000004b000000018577fceedd.1 PERMISSION:     read/write
VG STATE:           active/complete        LV STATE:       opened/syncd
TYPE:               jfs                    WRITE VERIFY:   off
MAX LPs:            760                    PP SIZE:        512 megabyte(s)
COPIES:             1                      SCHED POLICY:   parallel
LPs:                760                    PPs:            760
STALE PPs:          0                      BB POLICY:      relocatable
INTER-POLICY:       minimum                RELOCATABLE:    yes
INTRA-POLICY:       middle                 UPPER BOUND:    32
MOUNT POINT:        /home                  LABEL:          None
MIRROR WRITE CONSISTENCY: on/ACTIVE                              
EACH LP COPY ON A SEPARATE PV ?: yes                                    
Serialize IO ?:     NO                                     
INFINITE RETRY:     no                     PREFERRED READ: 0
```

I have added the entry to /etc/filesystems and mounted it

```
bash-5.1# grep -A 6 '/home:' /etc/filesystems 
/home:
        dev             = /dev/homelv
        vfs             = jfs2
        log             = /dev/homelvlog
        mount           = true
        options         = rbw,rw,log=NULL
        account         = false
```

After reboot the filesystem is not mounted and fails to mount with the following error message

```
Replaying log for /dev/homelv.
mount: /dev/homelv on /home: Unformatted or incompatible media
The superblock on /dev/homelv is dirty.  Run a full fsck to fix.
```

After repairing it with fsck it can be mounted.

I have not find anything helpful in AIX documentation.

**Edit:** Any idea how to keep the filesystem persistently mounted across reboots?

I would be grateful for any pointers

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I have edited my question. How to keep the filesystem mounted when the server is rebooted?

Comment: Would suggest adding `check=true` to the entry in `/etc/filesystems`.